# How can I call model methods or properties from Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, properties, django-admin

Is there a natural way to display model methods or properties in the Django admin site?  In my case I have base statistics for a character that are part of the model, but other things such as status effects which affect the total calculation for that statistic:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    base_dexterity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def dexterity(stat_name):
          total = self.base_dexterity
          total += sum(s.dexterity for s in self.status.all()])
          return total
```

It would be nice if I could display the total calculated statistic alongside the field to change the base statistic in the Change Character admin page, but it is not clear to me how to incorporate that information into the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice example from [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def colored_name(self):
        return '<span style="color: #%s;">%s %s</span>' % (self.color_code, self.first_name, self.last_name)
    colored_name.allow_tags = True

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'colored_name')
```

That works for list pages, if you want custom data on edit page, you need to [override template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Comment: These days those sort of methods are best defined on the Admin class, not the model itself. Just remember it then takes an additional argument, `obj`, which is the model instance.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Would the method look like this inside the Admin class? 
`def colored_name(self, obj):
        return '<span style="color: #%s;">%s %s</span>' % (self.color_code, self.first_name, self.last_name)
    colored_name.allow_tags = True`

Would the method still  be called the same way as in Dmitry's example? i.e. 'list_display = ('colored_name')'

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can this be used with 'fieldsets'?  I'm having trouble with using this in 'fieldsets'.

Comment: But how do you call such model funcs in the fieldsets ????  I want it in the detail page, if you will.  Any ideas?